# Confusion about Spring Caching abstraction and Hibernate 2nd level cache

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, caching, ehcache, second-level-cache

I've been looking at Jhipster to learn how to setup caching correctly and there are a few things I don't understand.

This is the [CacheConfig](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/main/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/CacheConfiguration.java) I have been using. It uses Ehcache with Hibernate 2nd level cache with `use_query_cache=false`.

When you annotate an Entity with @Cache:

```java
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity<Long> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;
```

And also in `CacheConfig`:

```java
@Bean
public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
return cm -> {
      createCache(cm,io.github.jhipster.sample.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE);
      createCache(cm, io.github.jhipster.sample.domain.User.class.getName());
   };
}
```

You essentially cache `User` entity with both **Spring Cache Abstraction** and **Hibernate 2nd level** right? So now every time you access a user you will cache it twice.

I can confirm is this true with a `listener` and `hibernate.properties.generate_statictics=true`.

On top of that Jhipster also cache on `@Repository` level with:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE)
Optional<User> findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(String login);
```

Overall I'm really confused on how and when to use Spring Cache Abstraction, Hibernate 2nd level cache. It seems like even with `use_query_cache=false` when you query `findAll` Hibernate will cache every entity that it returns.